# Motion animation which is scalable?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, scalability, motion

is it true: a motion animation always based on a Canvas element – the Element which move is addressed via attached Property? Unfortunately it’s not possible to resize a Canvas-Element at Runtime!? So the Motion gets wrong when the user maximize the Window.

How can I create a motion animation which is scalable in WPF / C#?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've add to my ansver one more thing.

Answer (score 0):

Draw your elements on the Bitmap, 
and than draw your Bitmap with scale as you want

If you try resize not the self drawed elements, you can use "Viewbox" - content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.

Here you can see how it works: 
http://www.wpftutorials.com/2011/04/wpf-viewbox.html